# LiveCycle: How to get absolute position of table row on page

Tags: javascript, css-position, livecycle

I am trying to achieve the following behaviour for a PDF created with Adobe LiveCycle Designer:

A table displaying data displays five lines per entry. The first three lines should stick to one another so they are all placed on the same page. This works fine by putting the pagination settings to "Following Previous", Keep with "Previous" and "Next".

Now the problem that I have been running into is that if the a table row is set to be kept with the previous line, the content of the table row does no longer allow for page breaks. So if I have longer texts in the last of the first three rows, all the rows will be put onto the next page rather than just having the page break within the content of the last row. If I allow the last of the three lines to detach itself from the previous row onto the next line, the page break looks fine but obviously is not what I want when the entire last row is put onto the next page and the first two remain where they are.

I have found this issue a few times on the web and there seems to be no solution to this. So the workaround seems to be the following: *Have a line in between the second and third row which keeps the two together and hide it if I require a page break within the third row.*

The concept works fine in terms of allowing for page breaks or not ... but I fail to implement a decent solution for **determining whether I want to page break**. I am believing that a good measure would be the vertical position of the first, second or third line. However I am not getting anywhere near this. I can read the **relative** y-position of the content of the line I want to page-break somewhat like this

```
var node = xfa.resolveNode("data.listpage.tablData.area51[*]");
xfa.host.messageBox(node.linDescription.frmDescription.txtDescription.y)
```

Where area51 is a table-area, linDescription is the table line with the descritption in it, txtDescription is the actual text. TablData is the table which is populated with the data. Documentation seems to hint that one way of getting the absolute position is to add the relative positions of the parents... but for some reason I cannot get the relative position of a table row, for example.

Obviously I would much rather like to get the absolute position on the page, even better the space left to the bottom of the page.

Would anybody know a solution to this? Maybe my assumption regarding the behaviour of page breaks and pagination also is not correct ... I am rather new to the LiveCycle designer.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Michael

Comment: You seem to have the same problem regarding page break control like me ([AIF: Ways to conditionally prevent page breaks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11781510/aif-ways-to-conditionally-prevent-page-breaks)). I am going to watch your question and will let you know if I found a solution in my case of the problem.

Comment: I did not find a solution. Luckily I had control over the data creation and was able to solve the problem on the other end.